# How to filter objects in array by category key in Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to use Angular filter to display only sorted tags by category

Example of a **tag** `object` in **tags** `array`:

```
{
    term: term,
    id: id,
    category: category
}
```

**The ng-repeat tags:**

```
<li ng-repeat="(k, m) in tags | filter: filterTags | orderBy:predicate:reverse"
    ng-class="{'selected': m.selected}"
    ng-click="selectTag(m)">    
    <div class="tag">{{m.term}}</div>
</li>
```

**The sort by category radio buttons:**

[image]

```
<div class="category-selection">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="catSort" name="brand" value="brand">
            Brand
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="catSort" name="client" value="client">
            Client
       </li>
```

**In the sort radio button directive controller:**

```
// Detect category sort
// Then apply the value to the filter function:

$scope.$watch('catSort', function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    tagsPanel = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsPanel');
    tagsPanel.filterTags(value);
});
```

**I found out that filter is has it's own Angular module, so my question is, how do I get the category strings into this filter?**

```
.filter('filterTags', function() {
    return function(tags, category) {
        return tags;
    };
});
```

Here is where I capture the new category, how would I send the value into the filter above?

```
$scope.$watch('catSort', function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: judging by `(k,v)` syntax in `ng-repeat` looks like iterating an object. Can't filter an object as well as objects in javascript aren't sortable. So much easier using arrays of objects

Comment: well is it an object? if so you can't use filter. Filter expects array input unless you are using it on a string

Comment: So you can't `filter` something that has a key value pair? Like `tag.category`? That sucks, hmm ok I'm thinking of a much more involved solution for this problem. Do you want to post the answer?

Comment: is that tag object in an array? If it is...you can sort or filter the array by tag.category...if the parent is itself an object no you can't

Comment: Yes the parent is an Array! :D `tags[]` is an array which contains objects

Comment: that's why i was asking about the (k,v) syntax which is usually an object. Ok...first argument will be the array, next will be whatever predicates you set in the html

Comment: I updated my code above, how would I send a value from my controller into that filter? Currently thinking of using `$rootscope` and broadcast

Comment: suggest you study a filter tutorial. Usually use them in html...but can be used in controller...try egghead.io and see if they have any...awesome very short angula videos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got it right. You want to filter your tag object array by category.

You can call a scope method and return true if it matches the currently selected category. The parameter for this method will be a `tag` object of your ng-repeat. So you can do a check like `return tag.category == $scope.catSort;`

Please have a look at the demo below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/b8uewuy4/).

(I've took sport categories just to have some dummy data.)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.catSort = "football";
    $scope.tags = [{
        term: 'foot1',
        id: 'id',
        category: 'football'
    }, {
        term: 'foot2',
        id: 'id2',
        category: 'football'
    }, {
        term: 'base1',
        id: 'id',
        category: 'baseball'
    }, {
        term: 'base2',
        id: 'id2',
        category: 'baseball'
    }, ];

    $scope.filterTags = function (tag) {
        //console.log(tag, $scope.catSort);
        return tag.category == $scope.catSort;
    };
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">Filter by category:
    <div class="category-selection">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="catSort" name="football" value="football" />Football</li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="catSort" name="baseball" value="baseball" />Baseball</li>
        </ul>
    </div>Teams:
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(index, tag) in tags | filter: filterTags" ng-class="{'selected': tag.selected}" ng-click="selectTag(tag)">
            <div class="tag">{{tag.term}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is exactly what I was hoping for :) treating my `filterTags` as a regular function rather than needing to use the filter module for this.

Comment: Quick follow up question, how would you reset the filter to show all again? I tried passing in just `' '` however then none of the items showed up.

Comment: Ah figured it out, just added an `if` statement and returned `return tag` if category all is checked.

Comment: Oh, you were faster than me. :) Yes, that's right. Or you could pass an empty string to the `scope.catSort`. I'll added that to the fiddle.